# Setting Grid RowDefinitions/ColumnDefinitions properties in a style

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

Suppose that you have 2 or more grids that share the same structure (Rows/Columns count and properties are equal).

Is it possible to create a **Style** and set **RowDefinitions**/**ColumnDefinitions**?

I have tried that. But I get this exception when the application tries to parse the xaml:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 14:9. Property Value is null or is not IEnumerable

My Source code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="RowDefinitions">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </StackLayout.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="(Grid #1) Row #1" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="(Grid #1) Row #2" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="(Grid #2) Row #1" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="(Grid #2) Row #2" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="(Grid #3) Row #1" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="(Grid #3) Row #2" />
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

**Position 14:9** in the exception refers to the first `<RowDefinition />` tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a better and simpler solution. The answer was just adding **RowDefinitionCollection** tag around the **RowDefinition** tags.

like this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="RowDefinitions">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <RowDefinitionCollection>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </RowDefinitionCollection>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </StackLayout.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="(Grid #1) Row #1" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="(Grid #1) Row #2" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="(Grid #2) Row #1" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="(Grid #2) Row #2" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="(Grid #3) Row #1" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="(Grid #3) Row #2" />
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think this suits the OP because it's not reusable across different XAML files. I could be wrong though.

Comment: I'd never heard of a RoweDefinition Collection

Answer (score 20):

You can't define `RowDefinition` and `ColumnDefinition` within a style, but you can create them as reusable resources. I think this is what you're looking for. Defining a `ColumnDefinitionCollection` and a `RowDefinitionCollection` like so allows you to reuse them with many grids to create a consistent look.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ColumnDefinitionCollection
        x:Key="MyColumnDefinitionCollection">
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="150" />
    </ColumnDefinitionCollection>
    <RowDefinitionCollection
        x:Key="MyRowDefinitionCollection">
        <RowDefinition
            Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition
            Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition
            Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition
            Height="100" />
    </RowDefinitionCollection>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

```
<Grid 
    ColumnDefinitions="{StaticResource MyColumnDefinitionCollection}"
    RowDefinitions="{StaticResource MyRowDefinitionCollection}">
</Grid>
```

Comment: Very good suggestion from @jf Alternatively you can create a class derived from Grid, set everything up and then use it everywhere. Well, I will put that as answer too :-)

Comment: Great answer! I was struggling making two columns of slightly different width in Android and Windows and this answer gave me the solution. Just defined the resource with <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ColumnDefinitionCollection".../> and worked perfectly!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, I get the errors: `The type "ColumnDefinitionCollection" does not include any accessible constructors` and `The property "ColumnDefinitions" does not have an accessible setter.`

Comment: @Alfie, I just tried this again and it still seems to work just fine for me. I suggest creating another question with steps on how to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @j.f., I found the solution. I combined his idea with mine and here is the result:

The trick was adding the declaration into a separate resource and referencing it inside style.

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <RowDefinitionCollection x:Key="MyRowDefinitionCollection">
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </RowDefinitionCollection>

            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="RowDefinitions" Value="{StaticResource MyRowDefinitionCollection}" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </StackLayout.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="(Grid #1) Row #1" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="(Grid #1) Row #2" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="(Grid #2) Row #1" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="(Grid #2) Row #2" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="(Grid #3) Row #1" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="(Grid #3) Row #2" />
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class derived from Grid

```
public class MyGrid : Grid
```

set it up and then use everywhere in xamls as

```
<local:MyGrid>
```

As j.f mentioned, it is called user control

Answer (score 0):

Nou you can't and in my opinion you shouldn't.

Defining a Grid isn't about styling, it's about layout.

From Xamarin.Forms version 3, there will be an introduction of more CSS-like styling capabilities. Maybe you then will be able to style a grid some more like you would in HTML/CSS. But not much is known about what and how will be implemented.

Comment: Hi Gerald Versluis, Thanks for quick reply. But it would be nice if it was possible. Because like a method you can change the code in one place and it would effect in multiple places. That's my opinion. Maybe creating a custom control will solve this.